# React Bootstrap application not running

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, react-bootstrap

I am trying to run my react bootstrap app with the command `npm start`, however this error appears

```
 @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.14.5 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

This is my package.json: https://hastebin.com/saforuvocu.json

Comment: Did you try npm installing @babel/core and popper.js?